# Jquery input value to url on submit question

Tags: jquery, url-rewriting, window.location

I hoping for a tiny bit of help.

I have setup a form which pulls the value from #keyword and submits it as the url.

The page is http:// mysite.com /tags

I am having two problems:

1. The .toLowerCase isn't working
2. The url updates though it adds the name of the keyword input (which is keyword) like so: http:// mysite.com/tags?keyword=MYKEYWORD

I would like io to look like this instead:
http:// mysite.com/tags/mykeyword

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#tag-search').click(function() {
          goUrl = http://mysite.com/ + $('#keyword').val().toLowerCase();
          window.location = goUrl;
     });
});
```

and the form:

```
<form id="tagForm" class="uniForm">
<fieldset class="inlineLabels">
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
        <label for="keyword">Tag Keyword</label>
        <input id="keyword" name="keyword" value="" size="35" class="textInput required" type="text" />
        <p class="formHint">Add your tag keyword and hit submit</p>
        </div>
    <div class="buttonHolder"><button type="submit" id="tag-search" class="primaryAction">Submit</button></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form is currently doing the *default* behaviour - i.e. GETting the current URL (because you haven't specified an action or method), with query string parameters pulled from values entered into the form.

To stop the default behaviour, you need to make sure you `return false` from your events handlers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#tag-search').click(function() {
          goUrl = 'http://mysite.com/' + $('#keyword').val().toLowerCase();
          window.location = goUrl;
          return false;  // Prevent the default button behaviour
     });
     $('#tagForm').submit( function() {
          return false;  // May be necessary to prevent the default form behaviour
     });
});
```

As others have also identified, you need to wrap the base site url in quotes when you assign it to `goUrl`, to make sure that it is treated as a string.

**Update** It is probably advisable to move your redirect logic from the button's `click` handler to the form's `submit` handler, as Stofke suggests:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#tagForm').submit( function() {              
          goUrl = 'http://mysite.com/' + $('#keyword').val().toLowerCase();
          window.location = goUrl;
          return false;  // Prevent the default form behaviour
     });
});
```

Keep in mind that there are other ways to submit your form besides clicking on the Submit button, such as hitting the `Enter` key inside a text box - using your implementation, when the user hits Enter inside the Keyword text box, they'll still end up at http:// mysite.com/tags?keyword=MYKEYWORD rather than http:// mysite.com/tags/mykeyword.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies! This seems to be working great.

Comment: Why do both click() and submit()? You can do just submit() see solution below.

Comment: I tried with just the submit() and it didn't work. I did however try the above solution without the submit() using just the click and it still worked in my case. Thanks!

Comment: the return false with .click may also work to stop the submit action but I find it more logic to replace .click() with .submit() as it runs when an actual submit of data takes place vs a click event.  That's probably only a semantic difference in reality but still.  

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tag-search').submit(function() {    
        goUrl = 'http://mysite.com/' + $('#keyword').val().toLowerCase();
        window.location = goUrl;
        return false;
    });
});

Comment: Stofke it does work though as Dexter had it setup where it was on the #tagForm form element versus having it on the #tag-search. Maybe this is due to the fact that it's a button and not an input? I understand now why it should be with .submit() as Stofke suggested and Dexter elaborated upon the reasoning why in regards to if a user hits enter versus clicks. The combined efforts of everyone has helped me a great deal so, I thank you all again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#tag-search').click(function() {
          goUrl = 'http://mysite.com/' + $('#keyword').attr('value').toLowerCase();
          window.location = goUrl;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the url like so:

```
'http://mysite.com/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes around the first part of the URL
Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#tag-search').click(function() {
      goUrl = 'http://mysite.com/' + $('#keyword').val().toLowerCase();
      window.location = goUrl;
 });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use **.submit()** rather than **.click()** and **return false;** to prevent the form doing it's default behavior which is doing a GET request.  No need to do both.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tagForm').submit(function() {    
        goUrl = 'http://mysite.com/' + $('#keyword').val().toLowerCase();
        window.location = goUrl;
        return false;
    });
});
```